# What contributes to extinguishing room fires faster?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When a room is on fire, the quickest way to extinguish the flames (so that it credits the "extinguish fires" objective) is to have the room filled to capacity with non-pregnant dwellers.

Powerful guns + high Perception work to reduce the amount of time that radroaches and mole rats disturb a fully-occupied room.

Given a fully-occupied room on fire, besides maintaining occupancy, are there additional factors which reduce the amount of time it takes to extinguish a room fire?  Perhaps stocking the room with dwellers who have a specific high-value SPECIAL attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many people have debated regarding what **SPECIAL** value affects extinguishing fires.  [This inconclusive discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3b2iwz/while_completing_the_put_out_x_fires_challenge_i/) implies that Intelligence affects the rate a fire is extinguished. Apparently, the only factor that might affect extinguishing fires is the room size. Obviously, smaller rooms are easier and faster to extinguish, especially if it's loaded to capacity with dwellers. *Endurance* combined with level also helps in these disasters; your dwellers will last longer while putting ones out.

Comment: I've seen intelligence cited a number of places, but never any good evidence. You link one of these places, but then go on to say that the intelligence doesn't affect things. Was that concluded somewhere and I missed it?

Answer (score 3):

Room level is also a factor I had a maxed out 3 wide living quarters catch fire and it took almost a whole minute to put it out. But disasters in my level 1 3 wide hospital are handle almost instantly. (My dwellers have very strong guns there.) even when I replaced two high intelligence dwellers for two nitwits things were still just as fast.

Answer (score 1):

In my own experience my fully expanded medical with only 2 dwellers in the room was extinguished much faster than my fully expanded kitchen that had 6 dwellers. I tried to RUSH on making food and failed ending in fire. It took them sooooooo long to put it out. Upon inspection, they are all stupid with almost no intelligence at all, whereas the medical is reliant upon high intelligence. Just my experience.

Answer (score 0):

A room will continue to be on fire (and the fire will spread to adjoining rooms) for a specific duration then it will die out on it's own once it has spread to another room.

Surprisingly, the room that was totally burned out will automatically return to normal operation once the fire is finally extinguished.

In short, no, there is nothing else you can do to reduce the duration of the fire.

(For reference, I just tested this on my experimental vault.)

Comment: Side note: It does mean however, that an empty room on fire, next to an occupied room, there's no impetus for fighting the fire in the other room. Just wait until it spreads to the occupied room and fight it then.

Comment: Objective: "extinguish # fires" disagrees.

Comment: You don't always have that objective. Just saying that for an end-room that's empty and on-fire, next to a room full of dwellers, it may not be worth moving them all into that room to fight it.

Comment: Edited poor wording again to clarify

Comment: Not sure about whether leaving a fire untended will cause it to be more severe - I've found getting dwellers onto it early will reduce the time required to extinguish, and the health effect on the dwellers. Also, an untended fire will spread to most of the adjoining rooms, leading to more work to extinguish.